# Java JDBC-ODBC cannot load driver for Excel

Tags: java, excel, jdbc, odbc

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class ConnectionExample {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("JDBC-ODBC driver failed to load.");
      return;
    }

    try {
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:abcdefg", "", "");
      con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

This code always prints

> `"JDBC-ODBC driver failed to load."`

I can't understand what the problem is.. I follow these steps:

go to `c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

`system dsn tab - add` -> `Microsoft Excel Driver (*xls, *xlsx, *xlsm, *xlsb)`

give Data Source Name abcdefg

`Select Workbook` -> `go to myFile excel path and add it -> OK`

and then run my code... where is the mistake?

Comment: Which Java version do you use? If Java 8: it no longer has the `JdbcOdbcDriver`.

Comment: JDBC-ODBC driver failed to load.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

Comment: at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
 at databaseExcelTest2.ConnectionExample.main(ConnectionExample.java:9)

Comment: above is the message i get ... 
(line 9 is--Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");)

Comment: @ Mark Rotteveel i use the latest version

Comment: @ Mark Rotteveel is it better or worse to use a library for excel  (hypothetically java 8 had JdbcOdbcDriver)...is there any other driver that i can use for this purpose?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a JDBC driver that reads Excel, but you could use POI. Note: add information like stacktraces to your answer, don't use comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JDBC-ODBC Bridge is obsolete and has been removed from Java 8. If you need to manipulate an Excel document and you are unable (or unwilling) to downgrade your environment to Java 7 then you might want to investigate [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/).